# jQuery, getting "500 Internal Server Error" when running a jQuery statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever the jQuery is triggered I recieve the error `500 Internal Server Error`, does anyone have any ideas why the code below might be causing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="../meta/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form1').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('I clicked it');
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" method="post">
    <button id="button">grab user data</button>
    <select></select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery? I don't see it added anywhere...

Comment: Why is the action empty in your form? It's likely it's going to try to post to / and if your page at / isn't handling your post then your server may throw your 500 error at this point.

Comment: @Jonathan Payne - No I have no included jQuery. I am new to the language and completely forgot to do so.

Comment: @recursive - My server has been error free until I clicked the button, and the code is the exact copy on what was included with the question. If my question does not make sense to you how else would you have stated it? If the error occurs and only occurs when the button is clicked then wouldn't it stand to reason that the button and code corresponding to it are somehow involved in the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want this will do the job:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#myButton').on('click',function(){
            alert("i clicked it");
          });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

`$(document).ready` is used to execute your code just after your page is rendered, then `$('myButton')` will get any element with an id "myButton", then you will use the method "on" to attach any event you want, in this case you will want to choose the "click" event, then you should give an anonymous function where you will put the code you would like to execute on that action.

Comment: At the moment nothing is happening server side. All the code that run was included in the question. I was testing to see if I had the syntax right before I moved on. I am new to jQuery, and have pretty much no idea what I am doing.

Comment: ok, so you are not using .NET?? It will help if you explain what would you like to achieve.

Comment: I am attempting to use jQuery to alert me if and when the button is clicked. It's a simple goal but then I just started using jQuery 30 minutes ago.

Comment: glad to help you, if you really want to learn jQuery, I strongly recommend you to take this tutorial: http://learnjquery.tutsplus.com/

Comment: Thanks that is going to be a great help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna guess its because of this variable:

```
<%=button.ClientID %>
```

There is nothing else (shown) that would signify anything else that would throw an error.

Can you clarify what you mean by 'jQuery is triggered'? Does that mean upon 'click' ?
Or just by loading this page (I assumed the later)

Comment: @BrookJulias -- Just to add for clarity, `500 internal server error` generally means you are having a server error, not a client error, meaning not related to javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @Jakub -- I am referring to when the button is clicked, and not when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Keven B -- If the error is not being caused by code then what could be causing this issue? The has been running error free until the button was clicked and the code was executed.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it's giving the error with this line:

```
$('#<%=button.ClientID %>')
```

Hard code a value instead and test it:

```
$('#buttonID')
```

Comment: I have changed `$('#<%=button.ClientID %>')` to `$('#button')` hard coding the id, but the error persists.

Comment: Looks like this is used in an ASP.NET Webforms application because the <%=button.ClientID %> call would replace the tag with the actual mangled button ID that ASP.NET Webforms generates during page compilation.

Comment: @BrookJulias With that being said, it appears to be a server issue, not jQuery.. You're importing jQuery correct - You don't have any includes for it? You could also try removing the button and just show an alert instead: $(document).ready(function() { alert("hi"); });

Answer (score 0):

Your button is inside a  tag with action="". This will cause a postback to "/". If your server doesn't handle this correctly, you will get an internal server error.

<strike>if you only want the alert to show, you can call preventDefault on the jQuery event object. Se example below:</strike>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#<%=button.ClientID %>').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("i clicked it");
     });
});
```

**EDIT:**
Forget what i wrote above. It doesn't work. Instead, use the submit event on the form. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form1').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('I clicked it');
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <button id="button">grab user data</button>
    <select></select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are attaching the `submit` event to `#form1` but your form doesn't have an id, only a name. You must select the form by name, `$("form[name='form1']")` or give it an id of `id="form1"`.