# Spring Mvc Passing Data from controller to jsp

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass data from a controller class to jsp but when I run it on server it shows null value but my id is correct and my query also returns desire result but when I get it from jsp it doesn't show any value. The error in console is 500 internal server error.
Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getmoviereviewbyid/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ModelAndView getMovieReviewByID(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws IOException { 
    ModelAndView
    model = new ModelAndView();         
    MovieReviewModel mrm=new MovieReviewModel();
    mrm=movieReviewDao.getMovieReviewById(Long.valueOf(id));
    model.addObject("review", mrm.getReview());
    model.addObject("movierating", mrm.getRatings());
    model.setViewName("getmoviereviewbyid");        
    return model;
}
```

Here is the jsp code part:

```
function selectli(listval,id){
$('#moviename').val(listval);
$('#movierating').val(id);
$('#auto').hide(800);
$('#exist').html("Word already exist!!");
$.ajax({
    url : "/cms/getmoviereviewbyid/"
            + id,
    type : "GET",
    success : function(results) {
        $('#moviereview').val(results.review);
    }
});

}
```

Here is my dao impl:

```
@Override
public MovieReviewModel getMovieReviewById(Long id) {
  return  (MovieReviewModel) getHibernateTemplate().find("from MovieReviewModel where movie_id="+ id);
}
```

Here is code for getting id

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin_getmoviereview/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getMovieReview(
            @PathVariable("name") String name)
            throws IOException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        try {

            if (name != null) {

                List<MovieModel> tagList = new ArrayList<MovieModel>();
                tagList = (List<MovieModel>) movieReviewDao.getMovieReviewByMovie(name);
                        //.findGallery(15441);

                if (tagList.size() > 0) {

                    Map<String, Long> map = new TreeMap<String, Long>();

                    for (Iterator<MovieModel> iterator = tagList.iterator(); iterator
                            .hasNext();) {
                        MovieModel masterModel = (MovieModel) iterator.next();
                        map.put(masterModel.getName(),
                                (long) masterModel.getId());
                    }
                    model.addObject("typemap", map);

                }

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        model.addObject("name", name);
        model.setViewName("admin_getmoviereview");
        return model;

    }
```

here is jsp

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $( "#moviename" ).keyup(function() {
                       if($('#moviename').val().length>1){
                           $.ajax({
                                  url: "/cms/getmoviereviewread?term="+ $('#moviename').val(),
                                  success: function( data ) {
                                      if(data.length>0){
                                            var str ='<ul style="list-style: none;">';
                                            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                                                var strtitle="'" +data[i].title + "'";
                                                str+='<li onclick="selectli('+strtitle+','+data[i].id+');">'+data[i].title+'</li>';
                                            }
                                            $('#auto').html(str+'</ul>');
                                            $('#auto').show(800);
                                        }else{
                                            $('#auto').hide(100);
                                             if($('#moviename').val().length>1){
                                      $('#exist').html("Word Not exist!! <a class = 'clickpointer' onclick='addNewWord();'>Click Here</a> to Add");
                                             }
                                  }}
                                });
                       }else{
                           $('#auto').hide(100);
                       }
                }); 
<script>

function selectli(listval,id){
$('#moviename').val(listval);
$('#movierating').val(id);
$('#auto').hide(800);
$('#exist').html("Word already exist!!");
$.ajax({
    url : "/cms/getmoviereviewbyid/"
            + id,
    type : "GET",
    success : function(results) {
        $('#moviereview').val(results.review);
    }
});

}
  </script>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="int_srh" name="q" size="" id="moviename"
        placeholder="Search movie" maxlength="120">
    <div id="div0"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="int_srh" name="q" size="" id="movierating"
        placeholder="Rating" maxlength="120">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="int_srh" name="q" size="" id="moviereview"
        placeholder="Review" maxlength="120">
</div>

    <div id="auto"></div>
    <div id="meaning"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $('#dialog').jqm();
    });
</script>
[Object]
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/cms/getmoviereviewbyid/150 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery.min.js:4 m.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.min.js:4 m.extend.ajaxVM238:8 selectliVM237:37 $.ajax.successjquery.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.jjquery.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery.min.js:4 xjquery.min.js:4 m.ajaxTransport.send.b
```

Comment: is there a stacktrace you could share?

Comment: Look in the server log-files. 500 menas there is an error in your code.

Comment: I have added the jsp script and error logs

Comment: do you have jquery.min.js script in your jsp?

Comment: Please go through this link.<br><br>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323237/jquery-getting-500-internal-server-error-when-running-a-jquery-statement <br><br>  This might help !